# Does itextsharp supports courier new font or any other registered font in c#

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I have pdf template ready with me.On which write values matching keys on pdf.Need to set different font and font size based on requireemnt Using itextsharp(pdfstamper).
But I want to set various diffent font like CourierNew,Arial and some other third party registered font.How do I use those different fonts using itextsharp.
Please refer following code snippet.
Following code snippet used to write values on pdf template
To set font call function SetPrintFont where different font and font size defined.
Please guide on the same

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(filebyte);
var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(pdfname, FileMode.Create));

AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
 { 

//set the field to bold
 pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), "textfont", font.BaseFont, null);
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");
         if (regex.IsMatch(de.Key.ToString()))
             {
                //set the text of the form field
                 pdfFormFields.SetField(de.Key.ToString(), response.ResponseValues.ToString());
             }
         else
              {
                  pdfFormFields.SetField(de.Key.ToString(), response.ResponseValues.ToString());
              }

            }
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
        pdfStamper.Close();
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of registerred fonts like this:

```
ICollection<string> registeredFonts = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisteredFonts;
```

Anyway in `iTextSharp` you can use any font you want. If you don't find desired font you can download `.ttf` file from the internet and attach it:

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontFolderPath + "arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
Font font = iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, fontSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
```

`BaseFont` is a member of `iTextSharp.text.pdf`

Comment: @alreat I cannot use Font Object with overContent.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize); I need to use the BaseFont.